# PROLOG - Split List

Tags: list, prolog

I'm using SWI-PROLOG and I'm having trouble splitting a list this way:

```
L = [a,b,c,d].

RESULT = [[a,b],[b,c],[c,d]].
```

I'm trying to approach this in a C/Java/etc. kind of way but I'm getting nowhere.

I'd appreciate any help in this simple matter, thank you!

Comment: Please post what you have tried & how it came up short.

Comment: Note that Prolog is very different from C/Java, so approaching it in that "kind of way" will almost surely fail.

Comment: @ScottHunter 
split_list([], _).
split_list([A,B|T], [[A,B]|X]) :- split_list(T,X).

This is what I came up with. It has a lot of issues, for example, if the number of elements is odd then it just returns false. And doesn't put the element 'b' in the second position, e.g instead of [a,b],[b,c] I get [a,b],[c,d]. I tried all sort of different approaches, like, for example, taking 3 from the head instead of 2, but the problem relating to the number of elements makes it unusable. In my head I'm still trying to figure out how to get the index of 3 elements x)

Comment: Try using a trace to follow the progress of your code's execution; there are a number of problems with it.

Comment: @RuiAlmeida if you have some code, please add it to your question, not in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is this:

`splitList([], []).
splitList([_], []).
splitList([A,B|T], R):- splitList([B|T], R1), R=[[A,B]|R1].`

The idea is that you keep calling split until you get to the case of [X] (only one element in the list)

```
[a,b,c,d] ->
[b,c,d] ->
[c,d] ->
[d]
```

At this moment you get to the second case, and the backtracking starts

```
  R1 = [] => R = [[c,d]|[]]
```

and so on.
Best way is to watch the trace.

Comment: `splitList([a], [])` succeeds